# Are the caret and dollar sign required/useful/superfluous in the PATTERN attribute of HTML5 <input>s?

Tags: html, validation

I have seen examples both ways, such as:

```
<input type="text" name="with" pattern="^[a-z][a-z0-9]{2,7}$">
```

and:

```
<input type="text" name="without" pattern="[a-z][a-z0-9]{2,7}">
```

In my testing, I haven't found any differences.
Do they actually change what is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the HTML5 spec](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#ref-for-compiled-pattern-regular-expression%E2%91%A2)

> The compiled pattern regular expression, when matched against a
>   string, must have its start anchored to the start of the string and
>   its end anchored to the end of the string.
>
> This implies that the regular expression language used for this
>   attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the
>   pattern attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any
>   subset (somewhat as if it implied a ^(?: at the start of the pattern
>   and a )$ at the end).

So it makes no difference.